# getting jsfiddle json content

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

The following simplified previously working code:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    //dataType: 'json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {},
    url: "https://jsfiddle.net/api/user/afabbro/demo/list.json",
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR)
    },
    success: function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    }
  });
```

I receive the following error:

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://jsfiddle.net/api/user/afabbro/demo/list.json?
callback=jQuery332 ...SNIPd... &_=1553587384' because its MIME type ('application/json') 
is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I initially thought that the issue was json vs jsonp or http vs https. All attempts return the same result.

if you run from the addy bar the browser identifies the mime correctly & you get the json as expected:

```
[
{
"framework": "No-Library",
"version": 8,
"description": "",
"title": "Hello World Example",
"url": "//jsfiddle.net/afabbro/vrVAP/",
"author": "afabbro",
"latest_version": 12520,
"created": "2013-08-08 15:03:20"
}
```

]

The code worked as recently as yesterday. What can I do to fix it? Why is my page disputing the application/json mime?

Comment: You are requesting JSONP but it looks like the endpoint is not returning JSONP. JSONP is just adding a `<script scrc="....">` dynamically so if the source you are trying to load is not actually JavaScript, the browser seems to disallow doing that.

Comment: Looks like jsfiddle has some bugs - I can't delete my old private fiddles today for example

Comment: The jsonp was just a shot in the dark based on a stack question. I really thought thet it is and should be json.

Comment: Any solution to the above question? I am also facing issue with jsfiddle API. Is there any bug reported with the similar issue?

Comment: None at this time.

Comment: Manoj, posted the answer that works dependably below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what worked and is working today (Jan 2020). Basically, here i have created an html table and I append the fiddle rows to the body.

```
var url = 'http://jsfiddle.net/api/user/[DESIRED USER NAME]/demo/list.json?callback=?&start=' + start + '&limit=' + limit; //&sort=created

$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    var box = $('#myFiddlesBody');
    var list = data.list;
    var title, description, created, framework, url, version;

    var item;
    var output = "";

    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        item = list[i];
        created = item.created;
        description = item.description;
        framework = item.framework;
        version = item.latest_version;
        title = item.title;
        url = item.url;

        var fmtdDate = new Date(created.substring(0, 10)).customFormat("#MM#/#DD#/#YYYY#");

        output += "<tr class='entry'>";
        output += "<td><a target='_blank' href='" + url + version + "/'><span class='link'>" + title + "</span></a></td>";
        output += "<td>" + version + "</td>";
        output += "<td>" + fmtdDate + "</td>";
        output += "<td>" + framework + "</td>";
        output += "<td>" + description + "</td>";
        output += "</tr>";
    }

    box.append(output);
}
```